# How Does Nuget know to use the most recent package?

Tags: version, nuget

When using nuget to install packages with the -excludeversion flag, how does it know what the most recent package is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `-excludeversion` flag does is tell nuget to put the package into a folder without the version appended to it.  The package name and version are still stored in the `packages.config` per usual.

Comment: Thank you Calvin! Was a little confused on how it knew where to look.